# How to retrieve data from external XML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, rss

I'm trying to show the headliners of a Dutch news magazine on my website. They have an rss feed: https://www.vrt.be/vrtnws/nl.rss.headlines.xml

I already have this:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {


var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      showXML(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://www.vrt.be/vrtnws/nl.rss.headlines.xml " , true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function showXML(xml) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, table;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[1]
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  console.log(x);
};
```

Why doesn't this work? My console says

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Research what the error message means first of all please. If the other party is not willing to add the necessary headers on their end, then you can not request it via client-side scripting directly, so you would have to go an set up some sort of proxy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe you should look in to how to include request headers in order to receive authentication. 
Try including these(user-agent may differ based on your browser):

```
upgrade-insecure-requests:1    
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```